# Timestamp is too far from current time, How to handle this type of error message and stuck in the loading page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, timestamp

I am getting the error message as below:

Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)" UserInfo=0x5d229c0 {data=<54696d65 7374616d 70206973 20746f6f 20666172 2066726f 6d206375 7272656e 74207469 6d653a20 31323938 39383936 32330a0a>}
2011-03-01 20:01:49.770 Warrantify[802:207] Timestamp is too far from current time: 1298989623

I am unable to go further and application becomes hang.
How can I solve this issue, Please help me out of this.

Thank you,
Madan Mohan.

Comment: What are you doing to get this message? He appear in the console? It's a leak? Your are doing a request? I think you could be more concrete than just an error

Comment: Hi, I am login through google credentials from sample applicaion of iphone then the above given message is displayed in the console and the application becomes hanged over there. Because of time difference. how can I solve this. please help me. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check the clock on your hardware; it may be so far off that server security certificate checks are failing.